# How can I push a github actions image to docker hub?

Tags: docker, github-actions, dockerhub

Hi I am trying to create an image of a simple project holded on github and push it to docker hub, but I do not achieve it.

this is my .yml file:

```
name: workflow 3
on: push
jobs:
 build:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
   - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
   - name: Set up QEMU
    uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
   - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
   - name: login to docker hub
     uses: docker/login-action@v1
     with:
       username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_NAME }}
       password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
    - name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
       context: .
       push: true
       tags: user/app:latest
```

but I receive this error: Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /tmp/buildkit-mount2002185417/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: The build step appears to be unable to find your `Dockerfile`. Please update your question to show the layout of your repository (a *link* to the repository would also be helpful).

Comment: ok, I have fixed it but now I need to name the docker image with the commit hash. This is the repository : https://github.com/agmcoder/Spring_workflows.git

Comment: The repository is private so we can't take a look at the files.